# php script not executed from command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, debian

I'm unable to execute php scripts from command line. I have the following simple code in a file named test.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
print password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

On executing, I get this:

```
#./test.php
print password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

About my environment, it's a Debian 7 x64 server.

```
#which -a php
/usr/bin/php    
#`which php` -v
PHP 5.6.9-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2015 11:03:27)
```

What could be wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to encapsulate your PHP code with the proper tags else it will be interpreted as plain text. Modify your PHP file to the following:

```
 <?php
      print password_hash("rasmuslerdorf",PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
 ?>
```